# Jquery autocomplete help

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

Ok need some help here. I have an autocomplete setup to pull from a DB with all of the right info. I started working with dialog boxes and it worked once but stopped a little while after. Does anyone see why my autocomplete wouldn't fill in correctly in this file?

```
 function clientJob() {
        showDialog('<p>Enter your Client Job Code</p><input type="text" size="15" name="projectnumber" id="projectnumber" value="" /><br /><input type="button" onclick="isaclientjob()" value="Enter" />');
    } 

    $( document ).ready(    
        function()
        {showDialog('<p>Is this a client job?</p><br /><input type="button" onclick="clientJob()" value="Yes" /> <input type="button" onclick="nonclientJob()" value="No" />');
            } // function
            ) // submit
            $( '[name="projectnumber"]' ).autocomplete({
                source: "job_validate.php",
                minLength: 3
            });
        }
    );
```

**job_validate.php**

```
$output = array();
$job = new job;
$jobs = $job->get_from_db( "`code` LIKE '" . $_GET['term'] . "%' AND `active` = '1'",'code',10 );

foreach ( $jobs as $key => $current)
    {
        $output[$key]['value'] = $current->code . " " . $current->name;
        $output[$key]['id'] = $current->id;
    }

print_r($output);
echo json_encode($output);
```

---

Looked at the old version and reverted back to it and it seems to work fine in the first dialog box if I have the autocomplete in there but as soon as I go to the next dialog box it gets screwed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing what is in job_validate.php it'll be rather difficult to answer. I would start by working back to where it was working. Adding in each line of code to see what's breaking it and then examining why.

Comment: @Mike - edit your original post and include it there; it's impossible to read code in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

> ```
>        $( '[name="projectnumber"]' ).live('focus',function(){
>             $(this).autocomplete({
>                source: "job_validate.php",
>                minLength: 3
>             });
>         });
> ```

Also remove the lines
`} //function`
and 
`) //submit`

Comment: Yeah still getting nothing in return

Comment: Edited my response, added the 'focus' event to the live function.  Working example without the job_validate.php: http://jsfiddle.net/8rsNB/1/

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you're outputting `$output` twice:

```
print_r($output);
echo json_encode($output);
```

Try commenting out the `print_r($output);` because it will mess up the JSON being transferred back to jQuery (since it's not valid JSON).

Comment: Thanks but I took that out at the start. Sorry that was just some error checking that forgot to take out.

Comment: @Mike Jones - You should update your post; it's there in your example.

Comment: @Mike Jones - Also, I noticed that your brackets don't line up. Are you missing something in your jQuery example?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using just one dialog box and going to different functions instead of multiple boxes. Thanks for everyones help.

Comment: Probably best to put this on as a comment on the accepted answer instead of a new answer.